# How to add a list to new column in pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I would like to add a new column with lists by iterating over every row in pandas

I have tried to use df.at but it gives me a value error

```
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': ['x', 'y', 'z']})
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        df.at[index,'new_col'] = ['m','n']
```

Actual Result:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "D:/Projects/fasttextproj/test.py", line 10, in 
        df.at[index,'new_col'] = ['m','n']
      File "D:\Projects\fasttext\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 2287, in __setitem__
        self.obj._set_value(*key, takeable=self._takeable)
      File "D:\Projects\fasttext\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2823, in _set_value
        self.loc[index, col] = value
      File "D:\Projects\fasttext\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 190, in __setitem__
        self._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)
      File "D:\Projects\fasttext\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 366, in _setitem_with_indexer
        self._setitem_with_indexer(new_indexer, value)
      File "D:\Projects\fasttext\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 611, in _setitem_with_indexer
        raise ValueError('Must have equal len keys and value '
    ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable
```

Comment: first of all,you should reconsider as to - why would you want to have lists in a pandas series?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`df['new_col'] = [['m', 'n']] * df.shape[0]`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
df['new_col'] = [['m', 'n'] for i in df.index]
```

or,

```
df =df.assign(new_col = [['m', 'n'] for i in df.index])
```

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer if it helped. Thanks:)