# Add a list into a new cell with df.at in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, dtype

I am trying to use `df.at` function in pandas to add a list into a new cell. However, it seems that the `ValueError` would be raised. I tried the following codes:

```
import pandas as pd
a = pd.DataFrame([])
a.at[0, "xx"] = [1,2,3]
```

It returns: `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.` I found that this error may be caused by the wrong data type of the column. I also read [another discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55336944/how-to-add-a-list-to-new-column-in-pandas), where @Loochie mentioned a method:

```
df['new_col'] = [['m', 'n'] for i in df.index]
```

However, the method above may not work if I only want to add value to some specific rows. Is there any alternative to add the list? Or is it necessary to create a column with `dtype="object"` first before use `df.at` function?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
a = pd.DataFrame({'xx': []}, dtype='object')
a.at[0, "xx"] = [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

When creating an empty DataFrame like so:

```
a = pd.DataFrame([])
```

The default `dtype` for the `xx` column is `float64`. You can verify this with `a.dtypes`:

```
xx    float64
dtype: object
```

So what you need to do is change the data type of the `xx` column:

```
a['xx'] = a['xx'].astype('object')
```

Now your `at()` call should work:

```
a.at[0, 'xx'] = [1, 2, 3]
```

`a`:

```
          xx
0  [1, 2, 3]
```

The behaviour makes sense because according to the [`at()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html#pandas.DataFrame.at):

> Use at if you only need to get or set a single value in a DataFrame or
> Series.